# Compare current time with a time in a row using SQL in MySql

Tags: mysql

first of all i have a table like this:

```
userID   Day      Hour   Class
---------------------------------------
65       Monday   08:00  Math 
65       Monday   09:00  Bio
65       Monday   13:00  History
65       Tuesday  08:00  Sports
65       Friday   10:00  Math
```

I am choosing the classes according to the current time.
When it is `08:30`  then i need to choose the next Hour which is `09:00` and it is `Bio`. And it is fine.
But when it is `10:00` then i need to choose `13:00` which is  `History`.

Added: lets say today is Tuesday and it is 07:00 o'clock. With the code below , I can choose tne next coming Class whish is at 08:00 on Tuesday.
Lets assume today is Tuesday and 12:00 o'clock. How can I choose the next lecture which is on  Friday (next weekday that I have a class on).

When I have no class in one day ,how can I choose the next avaible day that I have a class ...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like this:

```
select `Hour`, Class
from your_table
where time(`Hour`) > curtime()
and `Day` = DAYNAME(now())
order by time(`Hour`) asc
limit 1
```

Comment: Careful! the order of rows in SELECT result sets is formally unpredictable. You may not get back the row you hoped for with `LIMIT 1`